# SQL Server Management Studio fails to copy database because it's trying to use the wrong account

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am in a company that uses active directory.  I can sign onto given database in SSMS and view data fine.  When I try to copy the database to my local computer however, the copy job fails.  From the event viewer, I see the following error:

```
 Event Name: OnError
 Message: Failed to connect to server devsql73a\sql73a.
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.OpenConnection(Server& server, ServerProperty serverProp)
InnerException-->Login failed for user 'blahblah\W0219097$'.
```

"W0219097" is the name of my computer and I believe it is the name of a local admin account also.  I do not have the password for that account.  I am not currently logged in with that account.  What the heck is happening?  I'm using SSMS 18.8.  I've never had this problem at other companies before when copying databases with ssms.

Comment: Maybe it's company policy?! This would appear to be a conundrum for your friendly domain admin :-)

Comment: That is the name of the `SYSTEM` account in AD. How are you executing this, scheduled task?

Comment: Are you able to just take a `copy-only` backup to a file and restore that locally?

Comment: It is not a scheduled task.  It is from the copy database wizard is SSMS which uses SSIS packages under the hood.

Comment: I am able to make backups of the database to the database's file system.  However, I do not have permissions to log onto that server to copy the file.

Comment: @JasonCheng Could you try sharing a folder locally for `everyone` you should then be able to backup directly to a UNC path.

Comment: You need to discuss this with your people that control your server, database instance, network, etc.